# Creating Threads with java in AppEngine Standard Environment

Tags: java, multithreading, google-app-engine, task-queue

I'm new in Google Cloud Platform. I'm using AppEngine standard Environment. I need to create **Threads** in java but I think it's not possible, is it?

Here is the situation:

I need to create **Feeds** for users.

There are three databases with names `d1, d2, d3`.

Whenever a user sends a request for feeds Java creates three threads, one for each database. For example **t1 for d1, t2 for d2 and t3 for d3**. These threads must run asynchronously for better performance and after that the data from these 3 threads is combined and sent in the response back to user.

I know how to write code for this, but as you know I need threads for this work. If AppEngine standard Env. doesn't allow it then what can I do? Is there any other way?

In GCP Documentation they said:

> To avoid using threads, consider Task Queues

I read about Task Queues. There are two types of queues: Push and Pull. Both run asynchronously but they do not send a response back to the user. I think they are only designed to complete tasks in the background.

Can you please let me know how can I achieve my goal? What things I need to learn for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note:** the answer is based solely on documentation, I'm not a java user.

Threads are supported by the standard environment, but with restrictions. From [Threads](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/runtime#threads):

> **Caution**: Threads are a powerful feature that are full of surprises. To learn more about using threads with Java, we recommend
>   Goetz, *Java Concurrency in Practice*.
>
> A Java application can create a new thread, but there are some
>   restrictions on how to do it. These threads can't "outlive" the
>   request that creates them.
>
> An application can
>
> - Implement `java.lang.Runnable`.
> - Create a thread factory by calling `com.google.appengine.api.ThreadManager.currentRequestThreadFactory()`.
> - Call the factory's `newRequestThread` method, passing in the `Runnable`, `newRequestThread(runnable)`, or use the factory object
>     returned by
>     [`com.google.appengine.api.ThreadManager.currentRequestThreadFactory()`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/ThreadManager#currentRequestThreadFactory())
>     with an `ExecutorService` (e.g., call
>     `Executors.newCachedThreadPool(factory)`).
>
> However, you must use one of the methods on `ThreadManager` to create
>   your threads. You cannot invoke `new Thread()` yourself or use the
>   [default thread factory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#defaultThreadFactory).
>
> An application can perform operations against the current thread, such
>   as `thread.interrupt()`.
>
> Each request is limited to 50 concurrent request threads. The Java
>   runtime will throw a `java.lang.IllegalStateException` if you try to
>   create more than 50 threads in a single request.
>
> When using threads, use [high level concurrency objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/highlevel.html), such as
>   `Executor` and `Runnable`. Those take care of many of the subtle but
>   important details of concurrency like [Interrupts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html) and [scheduling
>   and bookkeeping](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html).

Comment: I want to ask one more thing are mutliThread increase performance when you are getting data from Cloud SQL ? I read many question on mutliThread performance in java but I think here situation is change I'm getting data from cloud sql which is in other mechine

Comment: I would imagine Cloud SQL would be able to handle 3 requests to 3 databases in parallel, so the user request *should* get a faster reponse time with threaded parallel database operations.

Comment: Check This Example https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.google.appengine.api.ThreadManager

Comment: ThreadFactory threadFactory = ThreadManager.currentRequestThreadFactory();
Thread thread = threadFactory.newThread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {/* CODE */}
});
thread.start();

Answer (score 0):

An elegant way to implement what you need would be to create a parametrable endpoint in your application

```
/runFeed?db=d1
```

And from your "main" application code you can perform a `fetchAsync` call from [URLFetchService](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/urlfetch/URLFetchService) that will  return you a `java.util.concurrent.Future<HTTPResponse>`

This will allow you a better monitoring of what your application does.
This will add network latency to your application and increase its cost since urlFetchService is not free.